# My footer is not recognizing the div above it and is therefore stopping in the middle of the page

Tags: css

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to make my footer responsive (sticking to the bottom of the page, no matter what page). I finally figured out the code to make it do this:

```
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
```

But now, certain pages have the footer stuck in the middle. What seems to be happening is that the footer `div` is not recognizing the wrapper (body) `div` above it on certain pages. So the footer just stops at a certain point and the body continues to keep expanding.

You will see what I mean at http://library.skybundle.com/product-training/account-settings/

I'm sure there is a simple line or two of `CSS` that will fix this issue. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set position to fixed instead.

```
#footer-bottom {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

That will stick it to the bottom of the page.

Fixed refers to it's position in regards to the browser window, absolute is it's place on the page itself.

By the way, that is not what responsive means in regards to web design. Responsive refers to the page responding to the width of the page. Just FYI to avoid confusion in any future questions.